# Twitch API stream search URL get total streams AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitch

I have an ajax function hitting the Twitch API to get up to 100 "runescape" streams.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=100&offset=0&q=runescape',
    headers: {'Client-ID': 'xxx'},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
}});
```

This returns the JSON response: `Object {_total: 95, _links: Object, streams: Array[82]}`.

But in my Twitch API URL, I've set `limit=100&offset=0`. I want the URL to return an object with `streams: Array[95]` to match the `_total: 95`. Because `total_: 95` is less than the `limit=100`, I thought I would be able to get all the streams into one `streams` array, but this isn't the case. Anybody familiar with the Twitch API? How come this isn't the case?

doc: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/v3/streams#get-streams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better go with:

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=runescape&limit=100`

Because as of the time of writing this it's a known issue they return less results then expected on the `search` endpoint

Comment: thank you, this works for runescape games.
Do you know why this only works for "runescape" but returns an empty object for all other games? ex. `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=starcraft&limit=100` returns an empty object.

Comment: @qollers make sure the game exist and that people are actually playing. for StarCraft II => e.g. `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=StarCraft%20II&limit=100` will do